# Solving a Diophantine equation: $y^x=x^{2007}$, $x$ and $y$ integers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, exponentiation

I found this Diophantine equation and to solve it I used the definition of logarithm but the solution doesn't require the use of logarithmic rules. I solved it in this way:
$$y^x=x^{2007}$$
$$\log_xy^x=2007$$
$$\log_xy=\frac {2007} {x}$$
Therefore $x$ is a divisor of $2007=3^2\cdot 223$, and the only possible values of $x$ are $1,3,9,223,669,2007$. How can I solve this equation with other methods?

Comment: How do you know that $log_x y$ is an integer?

Comment: @simonzack The assumption is that $x$ and $y$ are integers.

Comment: @Dr.MV Even if $x$ and $y$ are integers, $\log_{x}y$ need not be an integer. For example, $\log_{3}4$.

Comment: To conclude $x\mid2007$ we must have that $\log_xy$ is an integer, and we do not know that. Instead we can apply $v_p$ (the $p$-adic valuation) to both sides, yielding $x\,v_p(y)=2007v_p(x)$ implying $x\mid 2007v_p(x)$, which is logically weaker than $x\mid 2007$.

Comment: @MathGod Yes, of course.  $\log_x y$ is not guaranteed to be an integer.  That was not the claim.

Comment: @Dr.MV OP didn't claim it technically, but seemed to use it when they concluded $x\mid2007$ no?

Comment: @anon Please read the comment.  I wrote "The assumption is that $x$ and $y$ are integers."  That was the only point.  To answer your question, the OP seemed to use the further assumption that $\log_x y$ is an integer.  This was, perhaps, a second constraint that was not stated up front.

Comment: @Dr.MV Since you addressed your comment to simonzack, I assumed your comment was intended as an *answer* to the question that simonzack posed. Is there another interpretation of the intent behind your comment I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x=\prod_i {p_i}^{m_i}$, where $m_i\ge 1$ and $p_i$ prime, then $y=\prod_i {p_i}^{n_i}$ for $n_i\ge 0$. Plugging this in the equation have $2007 m_i = n_i x = n_i \prod_j {p_j}^{m_j}$.

Suppose that $p_j\nmid 2007$, then ${p_j}^{m_j} \mid m_j$ which implies $2^{m_j} \le m_j$, contradiction, hence $p_j \mid 2007$.

Also ${p_i}^{m_i}\mid 2007 m_i$. Note that $m_i$ is upper bounded. By your factor $2007=3^2\cdot 223$, for $p_i=3$ you have $m_i=1,2,3$, and for $p_i=223$ you have $m_i=1$.

You can now enumerate the 8 possibilities by hand using the above relation we derived.

If $x\mid 2007$ then everything works out. This includes $1, 3, 9, 223, 669, 2007$. The other two we need to check are $27$ and $6021$. Of these only $27$ works.